# What does "the cost" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

Langdon interfered Henry Shaw's meeting with Henry Shaw Jr:

> Langdon: There's strange things going on all over the city. The people behind this, they are not like you and me. This is witchcraft. Don't you see? Langdon. She doesn't want any money.
>
> Henry Shaw: Then either her story is worthless, or she's lying about **the cost**.

What does "the cost" refer to?

Comment: This style of questions… Is it you, Cody Steele?

Comment: These types of questions would probably be better suited at [english.se] or [ell.se]. They're about the meaning of words, the fact that they happen to be in a SciFi story is not relevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The cost" is the price Mary Lou placed on her witchcraft theory, which is zero. Mary Lou claims that she doesn't want any money for the story, but Henry Shaw doesn't believe her. He doesn't believe that anyone would give anything valuable away for free.

> LANGDON
>
> There's strange things going on all over the city. The people behind this-they are not like you and me. This is witchcraft, don't you see.
>
> Shaw Sr. and the senator look dubious-all too used to Langdon's
> harebrained little projects and interests.
>
> SHAW SR.
>
> Langdon.
>
> LANGDON
>
> She doesn't want any money.
>
> SHAW SR.
>
> Then either her story is worthless, or she's lying about the cost. **Nobody
> gives away anything valuable for free**.

He likely thinks that Mary Lou, in the future, would demand payment or recognition for her valuable story. Either that, or the story is utter nonsense. Either way, he sees no value in publishing her story.